# How do I prevent the result print repeatly in Python

Tags: python, function, printing

It works fine when make my own input number. However, as I ignore main() to check the first function and find out the result print twice when n_item = 15.

```
def fun_function(n_items, cost_per_item=27, discount_percent=10, discount_threshold=20):
    """Return the total cost"""
    cost = n_items * cost_per_item  # line 1
    if n_items > discount_threshold:    # line 2
        cost = cost * (1 - discount_percent / 100)  # line 3
        print('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, cost))
    return cost

def main():
    """Compute and print the total cost of a number of items"""
    n_items = int(input("Number of items? "))
    fun_function(n_items, cost_per_item=27, discount_percent=10, discount_threshold=20)

# main()


cost = fun_function(5, 31, 15, 10)
print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))

cost = fun_function(15, 31, 15, 10)
print('15 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))

>>>
5 items cost $155.00
15 items cost $395.25
15 items cost $395.25
```

Comment: When 5 `n_items > discount_threshold` is False, when 15 `n_items > discount_threshold` is true, so you enter in the if, and the `print` inside the method is called and you got twice print.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP just need to read it's code to find the duplicate print. No answer can help him.

Comment: The problem is when I try to move the print statement to satisfy the output, then the main() fnction won't work well

Comment: You should print the result in the main, you can't from one hand print inside fun_fct and from the oher hand print the result of the funtction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the print on the function where you always get a print

```
    def fun_function(n_items, cost_per_item=27, discount_percent=10, discount_threshold=20):
        """Return the total cost"""
        cost = n_items * cost_per_item  # line 1
        if n_items > discount_threshold:    # line 2
            cost = cost * (1 - discount_percent / 100)  # line 3

        return cost

    def main():
        """Compute and print the total cost of a number of items"""
        n_items = int(input("Number of items? "))
        disc_threshold=10
        cost = fun_function(n_items, cost_per_item=27, discount_percent=10, discount_threshold=disc_threshold)
        if n_items > disc_threshold:
             print('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, cost))
```

This way if you call:

```
cost = fun_function(5, 31, 15, 10)

cost = fun_function(15, 31, 15, 10)

>>>
5 items cost $155.00
15 items cost $395.25
```

You have to make a difference between the behaviour of your function and what you do out of it, like that print, which is not part of the function so it shouldnt be considered as "not expected behaviour".

---EDIT----

If you use the current implementetion written above and run `main()` and introduce 15, you'll get desired output.

Comment: Generally a method should just be computing stuff, and the calling method should handle the result, here printing

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to satisfy user wishes here.

Comment: So, how should i do if I move the print statement in main function?